# Can a spy reach the shack outside the second spawn point in CP Granary?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

While [discussing sentry jumping and the ethicality thereof](http://www.reddit.com/r/NewToTF2/comments/i34r5/what_does_the_community_think_about_sentry_jumping/), [Transall](http://www.reddit.com/user/Transall) [claims](http://www.reddit.com/r/NewToTF2/comments/i34r5/what_does_the_community_think_about_sentry_jumping/c20n0rp) that…

> There's a bunch of junk to the side of [Granary's second spawn point] ledge that [spies] can use to jump onto it.
>
> Edit: Just looked and it's only true for blu's spawn. You can still get up to the boxes by taking the ramp in the garage.

I'm having trouble making heads or tails of this. Here's the relevant screenshot:

[image: Dat ledge]

Sure, [I can jump onto the tires](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFN5D.jpg) and that might let me get a poorly placed teleporter, but that seems to be it. I also can't find the "garage ramp" Transall refers to.

Can a spy reach the other team's ledge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to crouch jump to reach the ledge from the tires.

I believe Transall wasn't referring to this area when he mentioned the ramp, as there are no container boxes on which you can stand here — you can only stand on the ones around the central control point.

Comment: Yup. It's possible. I've done it before (though its been a very long time since I played Granary)

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Yeah, those containers were also object of discussion as engies would build a tele exit there, a tele entrance on the ledge and be completely spy safe. I guess I didn't think about that though! (Also, I didn't know crouch jumping did anything special at all.)

Comment: Crouch jumps help you get to slightly higher platforms you couldn't otherwise reach with a normal jump (this is true of all Source games). It also increases the height of rocket and sticky jumps.